# Is there complete isolation between two sendalls in the same TCP connection?

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp

This TCP problem has been bothering me for a long time, but because it is difficult to simulate package loss in the local experimental environment(the local network speed is so fast that it is difficult to lose packages), I have not been able to find the answer.

My problem is that I want to implement an RPC between two processes based on the TCP protocol. The most efficient way is to establish a connection once and then this connection can be used again and again, so I don't have to repeat the process of three times handshakes and four times breakups. However, during my implementation, the packages received by the server were often mixed with multiple requests and they were not isolated, which caused problems for my design.

As we all know, after a connection has been established, if my client calls `socket.sendall(A)`, in which we assume that A is a package of 40KB in length containing the details of the request. Because the package content is too long, let's assume that the kernel automatically splits this package into 10 packages and sends them out in 10 times. We all know that due to the reliable behavior of TCP connections, if the ninth of the ten packages happens to be missing during transmission (and assume the client program happens to be dead right after all package were sent, so that re-send is not possible), then the application layer of the server side will only read the contents of the first eight packages and will not get the tenth package even if it was properly revieved.

My question is, if the client sends two requests in sequence

```
import socket

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect((HOST, PORT))
client.sendall(A)
client.sendall(B)
client.close()
```

and assume the ninth package of request A is missing during transmission, all other packages were properly recieved. Our server side use `socket.recv(4)` first reads package 1 and learns that the next 40KB of content belongs to request A, but there's only 8 reliable packages of request A, in this perticularly situation, if the application layer of server side continues to call `socket.recv()`, will it get a mix reads with the contents of request B?

If I want to ensure that the two RPC requests do not interfere with each other, do I have to establish a different TCP connection for each request, instead of passing the request content multiple times in the same connection?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TCP guarantees that data are delivered **in order** and **without any gaps**, i.e. if packets get lost the data following the loss will only be delivered to the application once the lost data got recovered (i.e. resubmitted and received) and delivered to the application.

TCP is a byte stream though. The "borders" between two consecutive `send` or `sendall` are not part of this byte stream, only the payload itself. This means that a `send` or `sendall` might not exactly match a `recv` at the other side - which is an assumption often but wrongly made. If some kind of message semantic is needed (i.e. something like "request", "response") this **message semantic needs to be explicitly be part of the data** and can not be derived from hoping that a single `recv` will always match a single `send`. Typical ways to achieve this are prefixing a message with a length or having a special byte sequence as message separater.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, what I do is that I measure the package length first on the client side and use 2 bytes to represent this length, for example I got a content of `content = b'\xFF' * 4096` , then I call `client.send(b'\x10\x00')` and then `client.send(content)`, in this perticular case, the server side is using `socket.recv(2)` to listen, once recieved , it will determine the following content length is 4096 and use `server.recv(4096)`, but I'm worried that this will cause the server to receive other content in the event of network fluctuations

Comment: @LeeRoermond "*I'm worried that this will cause the server to receive other content in the event of network fluctuations*" - It is perfectly fine to use multiple sends for pieces of one message, as long as you don't mix in other sends in between, like from another thread. Like Steffen said, TCP guarantees bytes are received in the same order that they are sent, there is no data loss without losing the whole connection. You are responsible for serializing your sends/reads to ensure proper boundaries between complete messages.

Comment: @RemyLebeau To confirm, I would like to identify the specific behaviors that manifest when an error occurs.In the situation described in the main topic, if there are two logical requests that are sent in 20 packages, and if the 9th is lost, does it mean that the server (application layer) can only read the contents of the first 8 packets in total, but not any of the later ones, even if they are sent through another `sendall` call. btw I'm curious if this would lead to error in a multi-threaded scenario, because it's not surprising to see multiple threads used in a real business cases.

Comment: @LeeRoermond: As I said *"data are delivered in order and without any gaps"*. All the `send` and `sendall` are part of a single TCP connecttion. And this TCP connection is a byte stream. Each data send have an associated sequence number so that it is clear where they belong in the byte stream. The receiver can thus easily find out if there are gaps and will wait until the gaps are filled so that data are delivered in order and without gaps to the application.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thanks for headup, So in short, if use the method I mentioned above, a server called `sock.recv(2)` and get two bytes of `b'\x10\x00'`, this can make sure the next `sock.recv(4096)` can only lead to two outcomes, either get reliable result of 4096 bytes or  simply get a transmission error(this also means that the connection fails), am I understand correct?

Comment: @LeeRoermond: `recv(n)` is not guaranteed to return `n` bytes. It will return **up to** `n` bytes. It might be that you need to use multiple `recv` to finally get all the 4096 bytes you want.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was trying to say, and maybe my expression was ambiguous. But the read not enough bytes can be controlled through the application layer, increase the read times will not make program confuse ,as long as they are in order at any cases.